# Laravelでバインド変数のようなものは使えるのですか？SQL　non -numeric error

Tags: laravel

以下のコードで Select をかけようとしたのですが、エラーが出てしまいました。

別の変数からSQL文に特定のパラメータを繋げてSQLクエリを実行したいのですが、良い方法はないですか？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
ErrorException: A non-numeric value encountered in file
```

**コード:**

```
$test = config('const.TEST'); //(int) 3
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE col = "+ $test;
\DB::select($sql );
```

Answer (score 1):

非常に基本的なことなので，まずマニュアルを一周されることをおすすめします。

- [データベース：クエリビルダ 8.x Laravel](https://readouble.com/laravel/8.x/ja/queries.html)

基本的には生 SQL は避けてクエリビルダを使うほうがフレームワークらしい書き方になります。

```php
$rows = DB::table('TEST')->where('col', $test)->get();
```

生 SQL を書く場合は以下のようにします。

```php
$rows = DB::select('SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE col = ?', [$test]);
```